# Should we PDO fetch or rowcount to check a row in database

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to find out which is faster and less memory usage when checking a column name in a table even if we had 10 trillion rows to check. Should i use fetch() or rowCount()  ?

Comment: The best way to find out is to set up a test scenario and run some benchmarks.

Comment: Neither are appropriate for checking a column name - rows and columns are orthogonal. However, if you meant "check for existence of a row with value" then I would use `EXISTS` - it will allow the database to "stop looking as soon as it can".

Comment: I gave a -1 because both methods have [**different (documented) semantics**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Only one will be correct for the given task so the very basis for this question is incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by "checking a column name" ?

Comment: i mean i.e. checking a user if exists in a database

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the question given, fetch() is the only way. It will do either for one row or 10 trillion (as you obviously would select count(*) in the latter case, for which rowcount() will always return 1, no matter how many rows were found).

But if you need just one row, they are equal. A content from just one row won't harm anyone, either in terms of speed or memory usage.

Speaking of user authentication, we no doubt will need some data, like user id, user role, etc. So, `fetch()` again is the only choice.

Strictly speaking, rowcount() has a very limited use in the web-development. A real need in this function scarcely exceeds one or two cases in a year.

Comment: you mean even if there where found 0 rows , rowcount returns true ?